# how to type event in react native with defaultPrevented?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

i am getting an event object from react navigation with its emit function. e.g.:

```
  const event = navigation.emit({
                type: "tabPress",
                target: route.key,
                canPreventDefault: true,
              });
```

the event type from above is like this: const event: EventArg<"tabPress", any, any>
but i get an error with defaultPrevented prop. e.g.:

```
//Property 'defaultPrevented' does not exist on type 'EventArg<"tabPress", any, any>'.
 if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
```

i have searched and failed to find a solution, i just don't wanna use any.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the "other" question, i think i found the answer, no questions asked.
I have been searching the answer on the internet to know avail, and had to go into their .d.ts file to refer there.

`interface TabbarProps /* extends BottomTabBarProps*/ {`
`state: TabNavigationState;` 
`descriptors: BottomTabDescriptorMap;`
 `navigation: NavigationHelpers < any,BottomTabNavigationEventMap > ;`
 `}`

I am open to any [other] answers. Here's my snippet of code;